# Кодировка русского текста в Perl

Tags: perl

Посоветуйте. Плиз. При выводе любого русского текста в стандартной кодировке ANSI в окне интерпритатора отображается полная абракадабра. Это происходит при открытии любого текстового файла на русском, далеко бегать не будем - тот же AkelPad, то бишь блокнот. Ситуация не много поправляется при смене кодировки на OEM 866. Но это вроде как не серьезно, а вот можно ли настроить сам Perl чтоб нормально печатал?

Comment: Спасибо. И как она меняется? Панель управления -> "Язык и региональные настройки"?

Comment: Спасиб. Уже нашел. ))))

Answer (score 1):

Радикальный вариант — переехать под Линукс/*BSD/MacOSX — и везде использовать UTF-8.

Я так и сделал :-)

Comment: Для перла никсы, конечно, самое оптимальное, и не только для него.

Answer (score 0):

Тут дело не в перле, а в консоли виндовс. Она использует кодировку OEM866, а внутри программы - windows-1251.

По поводу решения идем в [гугль](http://www.google.ru/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=perl%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&pbx=1&oq=perl%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA&aq=2&aqi=g3g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=2505l5811l0l7457l10l8l0l2l2l0l206l1224l0.7.1l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a93786fd470d623b&biw=1680&bih=845&pf=p&pdl=300)

Answer (score 0):

Советую Ubuntu поставить рядом с 
виндоусом. Сейчас-то проблему с кодировкой решите, потом 
опять она же где-то в винде вылезет.
Все равно ваш скрипт скорее всего 
выполняться будет на сервере на *nix